# VB.Net calling C#.net function with JWT token

Tags: c#, vb.net, jwt

To start with, I know very little about C#.NET.  What I have comes from a working example that I've modified to get what I need.  Trial and error.  What I have is a C#.net console application that works;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using JWT;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace TimeworksAPI2
{
class Program
{
    const string AUTHSERVICE = "https://workingURL/";
    const string twpAIPURL = "https://workingURL/";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int PartnerID = 222;
        string SiteID = "XXXXX";
        string StartDate = "2017-04-11";
        string EndDate = "2017-04-11";
        string Category = "vacation";
        string key = "XXXXXXXXXXX";
        Dictionary<string, decimal> Results = GetAccrualData(StartDate,EndDate,Category, SiteID, key, PartnerID);

    }
    static public Dictionary<string, decimal> GetAccrualData(string StartDate, string EndDate, string Category, string SiteID, int PartnerID, string key)
    {

        var apptoken = "";
        var token = new
        {
            iss = PartnerID,
            product = "twppartner",
            sub = "partner",
            siteInfo = new
            {
                type = "id",
                id = SiteID
            },
            exp = (Int32)DateTime.UtcNow.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 4, 30)).Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds
        };
        var jwt = JsonWebToken.Encode(token, key, JwtHashAlgorithm.HS256);
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(AUTHSERVICE);
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Headers.Set("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", jwt));
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
     ....
```

this works up to the point in the code; I get an authorized token.  What I did next was create a new C#.NET project, this time it was a Class Library.  I compile the Library into a DLL using the same code (copied and pasted).  Then I create a VB.NET console application, reference the C# dll:

```
Imports TWPAOI2Lib.TWPLIB

Module Module1


Sub Main()
    Dim sStartDate As String = "2017-04-11"
    Dim sEndDate As String = "2017-04-11"
    Dim sCategory As String = "vacation"
    Dim iPartnerID As Int32 = 222
    Dim sPartnerKey As String = "XXXXXXXX"
    Dim sSiteID As String = "XXXX"

    Dim AccrualData As Dictionary(Of String, Decimal) = GetAccrualData(sStartDate, sEndDate, sCategory, sSiteID, iPartnerID, sPartnerKey)

End Sub
```

When I run this, it doesn't work: I get an "Unauthorized" error.
I've double checked the data types / sizes, calling arguments, everything that I can think of, but I just can't seem to figure out what why it won't work when it's called from outside an C# app.  Just to make sure I wasn't doing something stupid, I created a third application, C#.NET, console application.  Referenced the same dll created above, and the call works.  Here's the C# console application that calls the dll:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CSharpTest
{
  class Program
  {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        int PartnerID = 329;
        string SiteID = "44265";
        string StartDate = "2017-04-11";
        string EndDate = "2017-04-11";
        string Category = "vacation";
        string Key = "XXXXXXXXX";
        Dictionary<string, decimal> Results = TWPAOI2Lib.TWPLIB.GetAccrualData(StartDate, EndDate, Category, SiteID, PartnerID,Key);
        Console.WriteLine("done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I can't continue the program in C# because it's not a string language for me; vb.net is, which is why I'm taking this approach.  I'm clueless as to my next steps in debugging / making this work.

THanks to all and any who reply!
Fred

Comment: And this is why you want Option Strict in VB. Look at your parameter list: `GetAccrualData(string StartDate, string EndDate, string Category, string SiteID, string key, int PartnerID)` Now look at your argument list in VB: `GetAccrualData(sStartDate, sEndDate, sCategory, sSiteID, iPartnerID, sPartnerKey)`. Note how you're passing the partner ID and the partner key in the wrong order. With `Option Strict` I'd expect that to cause a compile-time error.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out to me Jon;  I've added Option Strict (should have been there as default), fixed my parameter list order and it still doesn't work with the same error "Unauthorized".  I've singled step through both callers into the DLL and the values are as expected, only thing that I can see different is the C# app works and the VB.NET doesn't.  Thanks again; I apparently still need more help.

Comment: At that point I would look carefully at the request sent and the response received in each case.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the parameters in different order in the VB and C# examples

C#: StartDate,  EndDate,  Category,  SiteID,   key,       PartnerID

VB: sStartDate, sEndDate, sCategory, sSiteID, iPartnerID, sPartnerKey